# Multiprocessing of data held by multiple objects

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

First question here ever so I hope I get it right...

I have written a piece of code to handle multiple data sets in the following way:
- a base class that holds the data arrays (numpy) and all the methods to manipulate this data (bk subtraction, normalization etc.). 
- a second class that holds all the different data objects which I use to both apply the different methods on each data set and to calculate average values.

Now for the problem - if we take for example the normalization of the data, I'm currently iterating over the different objects and calling the normalization method for each one, however, since thees are separated data set, there is no restriction to calculate it in parallel, but, if I assign the normalization method call to a process once the process is finished I end up with the data set I started with.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


class Scan(object):
    """ Basic scan object """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Scan, self).__init__()
        # Init the object with some numbers
        self.data = np.arange(0, 10)

    def normalize(self, low, nlow, high, nhigh):
        # Normalizes the scan
        self.data = (self.data - np.mean(self.data[low:(low + nlow)])) / \
                    (np.mean(self.data[(high - nhigh):high]) -
                     np.mean(self.data[low:(low + nlow)]))

def main():
    data_obj_list = []
    processes = []
    # Generate a list of data objects
    for i in range(10):
        data_obj_list.append(Scan())
    # Print an example
    print(data_obj_list[0].data) #[0, 1, ..., 10]
    # divides the normalization to separated processes
    for scans in data_obj_list:
        process = mp.Process(target=scans.normalize, args=(0, 1, 10, 1))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    # Print an example 
    print(data_obj_list[0].data) #[0, 1, ..., 10]
    # normalizing the scans one by one 
    for scans in data_obj_list:
        scans.normalize(0, 1, 10, 1)
    # Print an example
    print(data_obj_list[0].data) #[0, 0.111, 0.222, ..., 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I understand the documentation correctly - Python is copying all the states to the new process and after it runs all the copies are discarded.

Any suggestions how to implement this parallel calculation (or reference to such example)? All of the examples that I can find use return values instead of storing the changes in the data object itself.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Provided - Thanks.